# Best way to backup Xbox 360 USB Drive

Tags: backup, usb-flash-drive, xbox360

What is the best way to backup/restore my USB drive that I use for my Xbox? I want to make sure that if the USB drive goes, that I can retrieve my saved games and such onto another USB drive.

I was able to show the content of the drive, however, I wasn't sure if I could simply copy the content onto a Truecrypt volume and be able to restore it from there at a later date.

The file system is not FAT or NTFS, wasn't sure about the impacts of copying from two different file systems... I currently have a DataTraveler G3 16GB.

After a bit of googling, I was able to find [this article](http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/backup-all-your-xbox-360-data-your-computer-0131811/), mentions an app called [USBXtafGUI](http://digiex.net/downloads/download-center-2-0/xbox-360-content/apps-pc/4046-xbox-360-usb-storage-explorer-xplorer-xtaf-v44-new-download.html)

Comment: Please note: This is on topic, as the flash drive interfaces with a computer.  Please do not vote to close.

Comment: @TekiusFanatikus - The file ssytem certainly is FAT32 considering the file system that XBOX 360 uses is exactly that.  It certains multiple 4GB files as needed.

Comment: @Ramhound Hrm... I must be confusing it with the original Xbox? Anyways, [you were right](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/usb-flash-drive#5c2b609d8c1a4d04a477c5309cb9944c)

Comment: @TekiusFanatikus - Its part of the reason you can't use huge flash drivers.  They have slowly increased the limits, but there is a reason, the 360 won't use a 3TB drive ( outside of the fact you can't get one in their special hdd case ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose something like ***dd*** on Linux would be able to image the drive, or else you can use [**ImageUSB**](http://www.osforensics.com/tools/write-usb-images.html) on Windows:

[image: 1]

A review on [this page](http://www.instructables.com/answers/How-do-I-clone-a-USB-flash-drive-to-another-one/?sort=NEWEST&comments=#comments) says it works well with Xbox flash drives.

Comment: Actually, I just tried with `dd` and nope, it doesn't work.